# Identity Server as part of Web API or separate app

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API app and to secure it, I've implemented `JWT Bearer` authentication. The next step is managing user access and issuing`JWT` token.

Initially I considered using Azure AD B2C but it doesn't seem to support my business requirements. So I'm now considering using Identity Server 4.

Is Identity Server 4 run as a completely separate application? Also, am I understanding it correctly that it is used as:

1. A web interface for users to register and login
2. Also a web app with API that issues the `JWT` token

In other words, does Identity Server 4 "act" as my own Azure AD B2C service?

Comment: You are right with all your assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdentityServer 4 is a Web app (Login & Logout pages) with an API that implements the OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect specifications. The [samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples) provide a simple user login and logout views that you can change to your liking.

Regarding the user registration process, you may add that to your IdentityServer4 implementation or have that as a separate web application.

**Similarities to Azure AD B2C**

This came from another blog [article](https://stormpath.com/blog/azure-ad-b2c-vs-stormpath-user-authentication)

Authorization

> Azure AD B2C allows you to model user roles as membership in groups
> that you define. You can’t currently get a token containing those
> claims, but you can use the Azure AD Graph API as a workaround to
> retrieve the group memberships, and use them in authorization checks
> inside your application. It’s a little tricky right now, but
> improvements to this are on the B2C team’s roadmap.

API Authentication

> Azure AD B2C can provide tokens for authenticating API access via
> OpenID Connect, but beyond that the functionality is limited. The
> OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials flow isn’t supported, and B2C doesn’t
> include any API key management features, so you’ll need to roll your
> own code if your services need to support API key authentication.

Another [article](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/IdentityServer-4-SharePoint-Integration-using-WS-Federation) with PROS for IdentityServer4.

> IdentityServer 4 is an authentication framework capable of out of the
> box Single Sign On (SSO) and security for your APIs, and most recently
> support for implementing your own authentication protocols and tokens,
> with a sample implementation for the WS-Federation protocol and SAML
> tokens. SSO works across all applications regardless of whether they
> are using OpenID Connect or WS-Federation.

**Summary**

IdentityServer4 is similar to Azure AD B2C with more functionality as noted in the linked articles.